# RegEx match numbers which have n repeating digits at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match numbers which have exact n repeating digits at the end in Javascript. However, my regex matches n or more than n digits at the end, and I can't seem to fix that.
i.e n=3, match these:
`12333
222
1233334333`

Not match these:
`11
12344
122233
123333`

My regexs(don't work):
`(\d)\1{2}$
[^\1](\d)\1{2}$
(\d){3}(?!\1)$`

Comment: Another variant: [`^(?:(\d)(?!\1{3}$))*?(\d)\2{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xY3Rqp/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - match the digit right before the repeating digits start, use negative lookahead for said digit, then match 3 repeating digits:

```js
const strs = [
'12333',
'222',
'1233334333',
'11',
'12344',
'123333'];
const re = /(^|(\d)(?!\2))(\d)\3{2}$/;
strs.forEach(str => {
  if (re.test(str)) console.log('pass ' + str);
});
```

Comment: Yep, its awesome. I literaly never used the \n thing in this part of regex, only for replace. I think this is like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle_problem : If you have been told you can use them this way, it looks so straightforward, but if not you probably never figure it.

Answer (score 0):

While this expression is almost resolve you need (it gives false positive for 4 or more repetitions) and maybe this can be fixed too ... i suggest to solve this with no or not only with regex. Maybe a [0-9]{n} and an exact repetition check with a backward loop on the string.

```js
let re= /1{3}$|2{3}$|3{3}$|4{3}$|5{3}$|6{3}$|7{3}$|8{3}$|9{3}$|0{3}$/;

var div = document.getElementById('out');

div.innerHTML += "12333".match(re)+" -- <br/>"
div.innerHTML += "222".match(re) +" -- <br/>"
div.innerHTML += "1233334333".match(re) +" -- <br/>"

// Not match these:
div.innerHTML += "11".match(re) +" -- <br/>"
div.innerHTML += "12344".match(re) +" -- <br/>"
div.innerHTML += "122233".match(re)+" -- <br/>"
div.innerHTML += "123333".match(re)+" -- <br/>"
```

```html
<div id=out></div>
```